# How to replace a word in a text with an image?

Tags: java, swing

Right now I use DefaultListModel with the wanted list of strings and I display it, via JList, in a JScrollPane.

What I want is to find a specific word in this sentence and to put an imageIcon instead of this word which I will display in the said JScrollPane.

For example I want to replace the word "cat" with a cat icon and the Strings would be:

```
"the little cat is good"
"there is no tomorrow" 
"cat is what I need"
```

and my desired output will be a JScrollPane with the items:

```
"the little *cat icon* is good"
"there is no tomorrow" 
"*cat icon* is what I need"
```

What I found are suggestions to create a custom ListCellRenderer to replace the DefaultListModel. In all the examples an imageIcon was added as icon to a lable, unfortunately this only adds one icon at the beginning of the text which is not what I desire.

Here is the relevant part from one of the examples from [this site](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-display-a-jlist-with-icons-and-text):

```
@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
    JList list, Object value, int index, 
    boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    // Get the renderer component from parent class

    JLabel label = 
        (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, 
            value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

    // Get icon to use for the list item value

    Icon icon = icons.get(value);

    // Set icon to display for value

    label.setIcon(icon);
    return label;
}
```

So, how can I add an icon inside a text in a JList ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you show what entries the `icons` map contains and the values of the `JList` ?

Comment: For this example lets say there is one entry in the map with key "cat" and value "cat.png". What values of the JList ? In my current program the JList is "taking" it's values from the DefaultListModel.

Comment: If you've added sentences to the list's model, this won't work, you will have to add individual words.

Comment: Also, you will have to remove the `JLabel`'s text if there is an icon for that value. Something like: `if(icon!=null){label.setText("");}`

Comment: A JList isn't the right component for what you want to do.  You need a JEditorPane or a JTextPane, where you could add icons to the StyledDocument.

Comment: Are you trying to add icon in between words in a text ? Then simple setIcon won't work. actually JLabel itself won't work I believe because using JLabel you can either put on left or right as far as I know.

Comment: But using tables as at : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer by cleverly designing cell renderers you might be able to achieve it.

Comment: Yes svasa you are completely right, I want to add the image inside the text, and JLable's setIcon as it is used in the example is not the way to go... I did look for examples/answers to my question with custom renderers but I couldn't find anything about my question (displaying icons **in** the text) hope someone could point me to a more specific documentation or show me an example. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **html** features of the `JLabel`, switching `cat` to `<img src='cat.png'/>`

Example

```
public class JListTest extends JPanel{  
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public JListTest(){
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    String[] data = {"the little cat is good", "there is no tomorrow" , "cat is what I need"};
    switchToHtml(data);
    replaceWithImage(data,"cat","cat.png");
    JList<String> list = new JList<String>(data);
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(list);
    this.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);       
  }

  private void replaceWithImage(String[] data, String replace, String image) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        String text = data[i];
        if (text.contains(replace)){
            text = text.replaceAll(replace, "<img src=\"" + JListTest.class.getResource(image) + "\">");
            data[i]=text;
        }           
    }
  }

 private void switchToHtml(String[] data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i]="<html><body>" + data[i] + "</body></html>";
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JListTest(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

To test, just add a `cat.png` in same package as `class`.

**The result** (with a nice kitty)

[image: Result]

Comment: Sorry for the long delay but only now I got time to try this. I run into a problem: when I try to write <img src=\"cat.png\"> it shows a "corrupt" icon instead and does not show my icon. when I write like in your example <img src=\"" + HelpClass.class.getResource("cat.png") + "\"> it shows again a bad icon and writes it as null. (the class I call it from is not main, its a helper) Also if I write ImageIcon cat = new ImageIcon("cat.png"); and attach it to something it shows the icon normally so the problem is not in the file...I couldnt find a solution with a quick search. Can you help?

Comment: Check how you load stuff via resources (the cat png need's to be in same package as your HelpClass..... if another package you need indicate the relative path (from your HelpClass)....

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `JTextPane` and the `insertIcon(...)` method.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for a working example.

The example just shows how to insert the Icon. It will be up to you to parse the text for the Strings you want to replace. Once you find the String you want to replace you can use code like:

```
textPane.setSelectionStart(...);
textPane.setSelectionEnd(...);
textPane.replaceSelection(...);
textPane.insertIcon(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in the program I need to display a scrolling chat window and I figured the best way would be to use a list and a scrollpane. Though I might try your solution later on.

Comment: @artembus, A JTextPane can be added to a JScrollPane as well, so I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: Well I can't display a list in a JTextPane (as it is) and I want to add/remove lines as needed because its a chat so a list was my intuitive choice.